# bash awk saving what is being outputted to a array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

How can I save the data that is printing out in awk statement? To be able to access in a variable or array?  There are 4 values (GATC) for each file it goes through as well as the total of all of them. Its iterating and printing each line if finds that fits the criteria to a file with addition how many of each line it finds with total of all four. I need to have access to the info later though.  Not necessarily the lines though it finds, I don't need that.  How can I save into a array I would assume to be best way to do it?

```
for f in $FILES
do
      [ -d "$f" ] && continue

      if is_file_contains_DNA $f; then
          echo "DNA exist in " $f  >> $SUMMARYPATH
      #touch $OUTFILENAME$f
      awk '/^ATOM/&&substr($0,20,1)~/[GATC]/{print;l++;a[substr($0,20,1)]++}END{printf "total line : %s\n",l;for (i in a) printf "%s : %s \n",i,a[i]}' $f >> $RESULTSPATH$OUTFILENAME$f
      else
          echo "DNA DOES NOT exist in "$f >> $SUMMARYPATH
      fi

done
```

Additional thought:

There might be a easier solution.  Can I print out to two files using "awk" instead of one? So I want to print the results file I have now and then add to single "SUMMARY" File, like I'm doing for the line before awk?

Comment: `array=($(awk command))`?

Comment: I don't want each full line of data, just the counter of iteration for the criteria if that makes sense?  Its looking for GATC and each hit, I want to add to the counter and keep track of that and each file I want to add to array list.  So first array[1] would have total of each GATC and total of all them...Second array[2] would have file 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use file descriptors from within `awk` to output some stuff to the terminal and capture other data in a bash array. For instance

```
#! /bin/bash

exec 6>&1

files=(file1 file2)
res=()
numfiles=${#files[@]}

for (( i=0; i<$numfiles; i++)) ; do
    res[$i]=$(awk -f a.awk "${files[$i]}")
done

exec 6>&-
```

will open a new file descriptor with number 6, which will be available within `awk`, so the `awk` script `a.awk` could then be:

```
/^ATOM/ && substr($0,20,1)~/[GATC]/ {
    print > "/dev/fd/6"
    l++
    a[substr($0,20,1)]++
}
END {
    printf ("total line : %s\n",l) > "/dev/fd/6"
    printf "%s ", l
    for (i in a) {
        printf ("%s : %s \n",i,a[i]) > "/dev/fd/6"
        printf "%s ",a[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a possible solution. I can't understand how I would incorporate iterating though each loop?  I was using a "for" loop before with $f as iterator.  There might be easier solution.  Can I print out to two files using "awk" instead of one? So I want to print the results file I have now and then add to single "SUMMARY" File. I update my question and add most of my code.

Comment: @MAXGEN Just input the summary file name into awk on the command line, then you can write to both files. Like: `awk -vsfile="$SUMMARYPATH" '/^ATOM/ .. ' $f >> $RESULTSPATH$OUTFILENAME$f`. Within the awk script, just use `print "xx" >> sfile`